# Can an user control be loaded in a child window in Silverlight 3.0?

Tags: silverlight-3.0, childwindow

Can an user control be loaded in a child window in Silverlight 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

so far the most you seem to be able to to do is change the color and position and size of the window. I am still searching for other sources though.

Edit*

My apologies for the long response time. I have continued searching the web for different sources hoping to find a solution to your problem. However all I have been able to find to date is:

> I’ve seen a few comments/requests
>   incoming lately that people like the
>   ChildWindow control in the Silverlight
>   3 SDK.  This is a great control that
>   creates a modal dialog for you.  When
>   you use it, it disables your root
>   layout application and shows the
>   dialog you provide:
>
> This is great for those true modal
>   needs.  It responds to normal windows
>   DialogResult type responses if you
>   have buttons, etc. – great for error
>   dialogs, logins, etc.  The request
>   I’ve been seeing is for the same
>   functionality, but in a ‘normal’
>   ChildWindow.

Found [Here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/05/10/silverlight-childwindow-non-modal-refactor.aspx)

But most sites seem to say that the child window can have either the the size, position, color, dimensions, inner text modified and the childwindow itself can be used as a user control. but nothing definite about having user controls loaded into the window. Apart from the link I posted,

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can, through the Content property of the ChildWindow. This can done in the code behind or via XAML.

Also, take a look at the [Floatable Window](http://floatablewindow.codeplex.com/) project on CodePlex. It extends the ChildWindow by enabling it to be resized among other things.